# Parse error while creating named Router in Angular 4 inside component

Tags: javascript, angular

Im  using Angular 4 for creating my admin panel. To the left I have a menu loaded from the primary Router. To the left there is a green-ish area in which I want to load another component. I used a new router named "console-router". However, I can't get the content to show. The other component has valid HTML inside and the primary router works great. Im getting a parse error when defining the  (link) that is supposed to show the "App Dashboard" content in the area to the left.

[image: Screenshot of the console]

I have defined my paths in the App Module:

app.module.ts

```
{
 path: 'console',
 component: ConsoleComponent,
 children: [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: AppDashboardComponent,
        outlet: 'console-router'
    }
 ]
}
```

Here is the link that is supposed to load the component when "App Dashboard" is clicked:

console.component.html

```
<li><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { console-router: ['dashboard'] } }]">App Dashboard</a></li>
```

This is the definition of the Router inside the Console.

console.component.html

```
<router-outlet name="console-router"></router-outlet>
```

This is the error I'm getting (As if it was a syntax error, but in Angular.io the code is exactly the same):

[image]

Comment: Are you importing the RouterModule into your module?

Comment: @Derked in the main module (Where all the paths are defined) i have: import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

Comment: All other paths work just fine (The ones on the primary Router).

Answer (score 3):

Well, for anyone getting parse error on a named router. The router **can't** have a hyphen ( - ) in its name. This is just the way Routers are defined in Angular.

Thanks!